# How to get CSS value actually used with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css

How can I get the CSS value used with JavaScript?

For example, I am testing on a canvas element with the css below but because it is not directly set to the element and is not in px which could be calculated via getComputedStyle(canvas).width, I am not sure how to get this value(100%).

```
canvas{
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to get the element by Id then you will get style property of that object.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
canvas.style.border = "1px solid red"
canvas.style.width = "130px"
```

```html
<div id="canvas"> <h3> Canvas </h3> </div>
```

This was you can pass the css property as a string, make sure you use right  [cssText property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration)

Comment: This only applies to inline styles.